# Using apollo-client in a nativescript app - process not defined

Tags: typescript, nativescript, apollo-client

I am using the apollo-client grapqhl client for grapqhl requests in my nativescript project. Since the latest update the apollo client is undefined after initialization.

After debugging the app I found an unguarded access to process.env.NODE_ENV, but process is undefined in a nativescript app. Any ideas for a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now reported this as a bug and they will fix it.

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/4665

There are some workarounds.

1. Use a process polyfill, e.g. [process](https://www.npmjs.com/package/process)
2. Set node env via webpack (if you are using webpack) as @Manoj mentioned

   ```
   plugins: [
       // Define useful constants like TNS_WEBPACK
       new webpack.DefinePlugin({
           "global.TNS_WEBPACK": "true",
           'process.env': {
             'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
           }
       }),
     ]
   ```
3. Set the process.env variable yourself (might not work if using typescript)

Before creating the grapqhl - client I set the process.env variable like this.

```
process.env = {NODE_ENV: 'production'};
```

Typescript already had a typing for the node process, I just had to set it and add the env variable.

Comment: You can also set this variable value under `DefinePlugin` in you `webpack.config.js`.